# Kafka System Tools for Replay

Tags: apache-kafka

I have case where we need to move data from one topic to other topic. I saw a utility in Kafka documentation "ReplayLogProducer". Its supposed to be run as indicated below.

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ReplayLogProducer
```

Does this tool require the partitions on source topic same as that of destination partitions? How does the retention of data work on the new topic?

It would be great if anyone can provide any insight on any best practices to be followed or caveats to keep in mind while running this tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command-line `kafka.tools.ReplayLogProducer` tool does *not* require the partitions to be the same.  By default it uses the default partitioning strategy: hash of message's key if present, or round-robin if your messages don't have keys. One of the main use cases is to copy data from an old to a new topic after changing the number of partitions or the partitioning strategy.

It's still not [documented](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-ReplayLogProducer), but the ability to specify a custom partitioner was apparently [added](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blame/6eacc0de303e4d29e083b89c1f53615c1dfa291e/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ReplayLogProducer.scala#L100) by [KAFKA-1281](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1281): you can now specify custom producer options with `--property`.  So to use a different partitioning strategy, try:

`bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ReplayLogProducer --property partitioner.class=my.custom.Partitioner`

Retention of data in the new topic will be however the new topic is [configured](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#topic-config) with `cleanup.policy`, `retention.ms` or `retention.bytes`.  Note that if using `retention.ms` (the default), retention is relative to the time the messages were *replayed*, not the original creation time.  This is an [issue](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-32+-+Add+timestamps+to+Kafka+message#KIP-32-AddtimestampstoKafkamessage-Mirrormakercaseindetail) with regular replication or `mirrormaker` and `ReplayLogProducer` is no different.  Proposals for [KIP-32](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-32+-+Add+timestamps+to+Kafka+message) and [KIP-33](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-33+-+Add+a+time+based+log+index#KIP-33-Addatimebasedlogindex-Enforcetimebasedlogretention) should make it possible to instead configure retention by "creation time" of your messages, but since Kafka 0.10 is not yet released, it's not yet clear if `ReplayLogProducer` would preserve message creation time.